# Does an iOS extension have an IPA file?

Tags: ios, swift, ipa, ios8-share-extension

I was wondering if a share extension creates an .ipa file similarly to a regular target?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's packaged in your app's IPA and delivered to Apple as a single file with it (and everything else).

An IPA itself is a zip format file -- if you make a copy of one and rename it to .zip, you can unzip it and look at what it has.

At the top level it has a `Payload` folder with a `.app` file in it.  That file is a package (you can right-click and show contents). In there, you'll find a `PlugIns` folder, which will have `*.appex` files.  These are what your extension targets build.

So, the IPA's `Payload/NAME.app/PlugIns/*.appex` packages are the extensions.

Comment: That makes sense, Thank you